# How to give points for each indices of list

Tags: python-3.x

```
def voting_borda(rank_ballots):
    '''(list of list of str) -> tuple of (str, list of int)
```

The parameter is a list of 4-element lists that represent rank ballots for a single riding.

The [Borda Count](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borda_count) is determined by assigning points according to ranking. A party gets 3 points for each first-choice ranking, 2 points for each second-choice ranking and 1 point for each third-choice ranking. (No points are awarded for being ranked fourth.) For example, the rank ballot shown above would contribute 3 points to the Liberal count, 2 points to the Green count and 1 point to the CPC count. The party that receives the most points wins the seat.

Return a tuple where the first element is the name of the winning party according to Borda Count and the second element is a four-element list that contains the total number of points for each party. The order of the list elements corresponds to the order of the parties in PARTY_INDICES.

```
#>>> voting_borda([['GREEN','NDP', 'LIBERAL', 'CPC'], ['GREEN','CPC','LIBERAL','NDP'],
    ['LIBERAL','NDP', 'CPC', 'GREEN']])
#('GREEN',[4, 6, 5, 3])

list_of_party_order = []
for sublist in rank_ballots:
    for party in sublist[0]:
        if party == 'GREEN':
            GREEN_COUNT += 3
        elif party == 'NDP':
            NDP_COUNT += 3
        elif party == 'LIBERAL':
            LIBERAL_COUNT += 3
        elif party == 'CPC':
            CPC_COUNT += 3

    for party in sublist[1]:
        if party == 'GREEN':
            GREEN_COUNT += 2
        elif party == 'NDP':
            NDP_COUNT += 2
        elif party == 'LIBERAL':
            LIBERAL_COUNT += 2
        elif party == 'CPC':
            CPC_COUNT += 2

   for party in sublist[2]:
        if party == 'GREEN':
            GREEN_COUNT += 1
        elif party == 'NDP':
            NDP_COUNT += 1
        elif party == 'LIBERAL':
            LIBERAL_COUNT += 1
        elif party == 'CPC':
            CPC_COUNT += 1
```

I don't know how I would give points for each indices of the list MORE SIMPLY.
Can someone please help me? Without being too complicated. Thank you!

Comment: Please someone kindly offer help or guide, I am stuck on this function for 2 hours erasing and writing back and forth.

Comment: PARTY_INDICES = [NDP_INDEX, GREEN_INDEX, LIBERAL_INDEX, CPC_INDEX]

Comment: I could try to help, but your question looks way too complicated. Please globalize it, so that it's not for your particular program. Make it simple

Comment: For example, instead of asking "I got a list of playing cards which all have a number, a suit and an owner, how do I add them to a dictionary which is held inside my Deck -object?" ask "I got a list of objects, how do I add them to a dictionary?". Try figuring the method you must use, and for that you don't need complicated names and objects. This way you will get much more answers, and people realize easier what you're asking

Comment: So what I am trying to do is giving 3 points for sublist[0], 2 points for sublist[1] and 1 point for sublist[2] and 0 point for sublist[3] but sublist contain different parties and I need to give points for  specific party in the index of that sublist. It would really be too long to make 16 if statements saying

Comment: for example, for party in sublist[0]: if party == Green: Green_count += 3

Comment: is there a simpler way??

Comment: It's really difficult to generalize this question though.

Comment: I'll start working on it, check back in half an hour.

Answer (score 0):

This does not do **EXACTLY** what you were asking for, it returns a tuple with two values: winner's name, and a **dictionary** of all parties and their values, instead of a list with only values. In my opinion, this is better for almost any case, and if you don't like it, you can convert it to a list.

It also takes multiple parameters instead of one list too, but you can change that by simply removing the `*` from `*args`

Notice, however, if you care about speed rather than small code, this is not the best way to do it. It does work, tho.

It is also superior to your code in the manner of this allowing you to NOT use any of the parties names or amount of parties inside the function, which makes it possible to add, rename or remove parties.

```
def voting_borda(*args):
    results = {}
    for sublist in args:
        for i in range(0, 3):
            if sublist[i] in results:
                results[sublist[i]] += 3-i
            else:
                results[sublist[i]] = 3-i

    winner = max(results, key=results.get)
    return winner, results

print(voting_borda(
    ['GREEN','NDP', 'LIBERAL', 'CPC'],
    ['GREEN','CPC','LIBERAL','NDP'],
    ['LIBERAL','NDP', 'CPC', 'GREEN']
))
```

Will result into: `('GREEN', {'LIBERAL': 5, 'NDP': 4, 'GREEN': 6, 'CPC': 3})`

Answer (score 0):

I found your voting simulation assignment [online](http://www.cdf.toronto.edu/~csc108h/fall/assignments/a2/handout/index.shtml) and added a few of the constants from it here to simplify the code for solving the problem a little (although it may not look like it with their definitions at the beginning).

The first element of the tuple returned is not *exactly* in the requested format -- it's a list rather than a single value -- to deal with the quite real possibility of tie votes, as illustrated with the sample data values used below for `rank_ballots`. Even if there wasn't a tie, the element is return is a singleton list -- which actually is usually easier to deal with than having it vary depending on there's more than one or not.

```
PARTY_NAMES = ['NDP', 'GREEN', 'LIBERAL', 'CPC']
NAME_TO_INDEX = {party:PARTY_NAMES.index(party) for party in PARTY_NAMES}
INDEX_TO_NAME = {PARTY_NAMES.index(party):party for party in PARTY_NAMES}

def voting_borda(rank_ballots):
    results = [0 for _ in PARTY_NAMES]
    MAX_POINTS = len(PARTY_NAMES)-1
    for ballot in rank_ballots:
        for i,party in enumerate(ballot):
            results[NAME_TO_INDEX[party]] += MAX_POINTS-i

    highest_rank = max(results)
    winners = [INDEX_TO_NAME[i] for i,total in enumerate(results) if total == highest_rank]
    return winners, results

rank_ballots = [['GREEN','NDP', 'LIBERAL', 'CPC'],
                ['GREEN','CPC','LIBERAL','NDP'],
                ['LIBERAL', 'GREEN', 'NDP', 'CPC'],
                ['LIBERAL','NDP', 'CPC', 'GREEN'],]

print(voting_borda(rank_ballots))
```

Output:

```
(['GREEN', 'LIBERAL'], [5, 8, 8, 3])
```