# How can I change the output? (Python, lists, dictionaries help)

Tags: python, python-3.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [changing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639268/changing-the-output)

This is the code:

```
def voting_borda(args):
    results = {}
    for sublist in args:
        for i in range(0, 3):
            if sublist[i] in results:
                results[sublist[i]] += 3-i
            else:
                results[sublist[i]] = 3-i

    winner = max(results, key=results.get)
    return winner, results

print(voting_borda(
    ['GREEN','NDP', 'LIBERAL', 'CPC'],
    ['GREEN','CPC','LIBERAL','NDP'],
    ['LIBERAL','NDP', 'CPC', 'GREEN']
))
```

The output produced is

```
"('GREEN', {'LIBERAL': 5, 'NDP': 4, 'GREEN': 6, 'CPC': 3})"
```

I don't want the party names in the output (liberal, ndp, green and cpc) I just need the values, How can I edit the code to achieve that?

edit:

the error message i got after testing the above code (with: >>>voting_borda([['NDP', 'CPC', 'GREEN', 'LIBERAL'],['NDP', 'CPC', 'LIBERAL', 'GREEN'],['NDP', 'CPC', 'GREEN', 'LIBERAL']])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    voting_borda([['NDP', 'CPC', 'GREEN', 'LIBERAL'],['NDP', 'CPC', 'LIBERAL', 'GREEN'],['NDP', 'CPC', 'GREEN', 'LIBERAL']])
  File "C:\Users\mycomp\Desktop\work\voting_systems.py", line 144, in voting_borda
    winner = max(results, key=results.get)
NameError: global name 'results' is not defined

> > > 

Comment: See my post. It covers both.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am able to run my module efficiently, however when when I try a test case, it gives me error saying "global name 'results' is not defined'' how may I fix this? thanks in advance

Comment: Look at my post, made a change. Is this what you are doing ?

Comment: Yes I added "return winner, list(results.values())" instead of "return winner, results" and kept the rest of the code same

Comment: Post you code in the question with error message, below the original question.

Comment: Your classmates already [asked this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639268/changing-the-output) and [here as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542458/how-to-give-points-for-each-indices-of-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python 2.7 :

```
return winner, [value for value in results.values()])
```

For Python 3.x :

```
return winner, list(results.values())
```

Comment: Why not just `return winner, results.values()` ? (or `list(results.values())` in 3.x ?

Comment: @JonClements results.values() returns a dict_values() object which is iterable but doesnt look clean on printing

Comment: I mentioned both 2.x and 3.x options...

Comment: @JonClements Mentioned where ?

Comment: (or list(results.values()) in 3.x ? – Jon Clements 13 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

Very old fashioned Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

myResults=(['GREEN','NDP', 'LIBERAL', 'CPC'],
    ['GREEN','CPC','LIBERAL','NDP'],
    ['LIBERAL','NDP', 'CPC', 'GREEN'])

def count(results):
  counter = dict()
  for resultList in results:
    for result in resultList:
      if not(result in counter):
        counter[result] = 1
      else:
        counter[result] += 1
  print "counter (before): %s" % counter
  return counter.values()


if __name__ == "__main__":
  print "%s" % count(myResults)
```

If you're using Python >= 2.7, check the "[collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects)" (as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5829377/289011))